# camel 2.21.0 - pgp encryption not working

Tags: encryption, apache-camel, pgp, openpgp, spring-camel

Trying to use latest camle's pgp encryption, but seeing `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection` error, I have checked I have correct versions of camel and bouncy castle jars on classpath, also tried with latest 1.59 bc version. - am I missing anything?

```
mvn dependency:tree|egrep 'bcp|crypto'
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-crypto:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-crypto:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lorg/bouncycastle/openpgp/operator/KeyFingerPrintCalculator;)V
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPDataFormatUtil.findPublicKeys(PGPDataFormatUtil.java:204)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPDataFormatUtil.findPublicKeys(PGPDataFormatUtil.java:96)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPDataFormat.getEncryptionKeys(PGPDataFormat.java:235)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.marshal(PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.java:222)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:69)
```

---

**Test Route:**

```
  class DeadLetterChannelRoute1 extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:source/inbox")
                    //.errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("file:source/dlc1").useOriginalMessage())
                    .process(exchange -> System.out.println( "1 >>> BEFORE:\n " + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)))
                    .marshal().pgp(encryptKeyFileName,encryptKeyUserid)
                    .process(exchange -> System.out.println( "1 >>> AFTER: \n" +  exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)))
                    .to("file:source/pgp_inbox");
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Also checked that on runtime these jars are in classpath: `:~/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk15on/1.57/bcpg-jdk15on-1.57.jar:~/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.57/bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar:`

***So it turned out that jdk version wasn't a problem, but issue was when we renamed the older bc jars in java installation `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` dir with `.out` we assumed these jars are not being loaded on classpath, but it seems they do get loaded. When I deleted these older jar completely from  `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`, everything works with both java 8 versions 121 and 172.***

Comment: opened a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12574

Comment: see last paragraph for solution